# Can my supervisor adjust and publish my bachelor's thesis without mentioning me as a co-author?

Tags: publications, thesis, supervision, bachelor

I have wrote a bachelor's thesis, and the research department is very enthusiastic about it. Now they want to make a publication of it. My PI asked my supervisor to make this review. Now they are going to make a whole new review, based on my review. They are using the method I used, and probably the data I have found. It actually comes down to that they are redoing my bachelor's thesis so that it will be publishable. Can they do this without mentioning me as a co-author? I put in a lot of work on this bachelor's thesis and I already told my supervisor that I wanted to collaborate if we went to publish the thesis.

Comment: Did they say they will not mention you? I would first make sure where you stand, most likely they will appreciate your help and also give you credit for your work.

Comment: Are you sure your interpretation of their intent is correct? Why would they spend so much time and effort re-doing everything?

Comment: It did not seem they want to involve me in the publication. We have not discussed any acknowledgements. The bachelor's thesis i made is not according to the guidelines needed to publish, so they need to redo some things, but it will approximately have the same outcome. I hear from other students also that some supervisors publish their thesis without any acknowledgements to the student. I fear the same will happen to me.

Comment: Rather than making assumptions on what you have heard from other students take the initiative to actually discuss your concerns with your PI and your supervisor what the intention is with your work and the attributions. If you don't make the effort then you might end up like those you talked to. It could have been that they didn't put in any effort to ensure they got attribution so they were ignored. Don't let yourself be ignored.

Comment: The way OP describes it - the thesis appears to similar to a course report - (student writes report on topic of interest related to his advisor's expertise, e.g., "Detectors for Dark Matter"  and finds and reads some relevant literature). Is this accurate assessment? The group has been energized into writing a review paper on topic  ( presumably related to the work that goes on in their labs and programs, etc) and will do their own more extensive literature review and dig deeper, etc. I'm not sure this falls quite into the same bucket as using a student's research work without acknowledgement?

Comment: This sounds like some phd's saying they will redo the work but not adding anything. They might do the actual work but in fact are just doing research that follows in a sure publishable paper. Bad academics caused by a incentive to have as muchs papers on your own name. You should get the credit. You did the risky research that might end in dead enc. They should help you get the thesis publishable. It sounds like some has to be rewritten in a different format, minor errors fixed.

Comment: Your thesis is only a literature review? If there is additional own work by you in it, however: That can't go into a review paper. Sorry, If they are only borrowing your literature list, then there is little reason why you should be an author. An acknowledgement might be a nice gesture.

Comment: Either way, it might be a good idea to slightly rewrite the thesis in article format and post it on a preprint server (if your university allows it), to clearly show your work and claim "priority" (in a sense...).

Comment: I talked with my supervisor about it and we both agreed it would be fair if i became one the authors. I think it was a good idea to talk to the supervisor and explain my vision. Now they want me to cooperate in the publication.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is: Can they do this without mentioning me as a co-author?

The answer is unambiguously: No.